# jQuery automated creation of links from ID in <a> tag

Tags: php, jquery

I'm a beginner so please be patient. Tried this myself but can't get it to work.

I'm creating a hardcoded lexicon (no DB behind it but 26 a-z pages) - in the code the links will be "lazily" written as such:

```
<div class="lexicon">
    <a id="letter-a"></a>
    <a id="letter-b"></a>
    <a id="letter-c"></a>
    etc.
</div>
```

I then want a small jquery script before this to "get" the id, strip the "letter-" part and...

1. add a link to the a-Tag (ie. mylexicon/mypage-a)
2. add the stripped id as text for the a-Tag

The result should then be:

```
<a id="letter-a" href="mylexicon/mypage-a">a</a>
```

Got this far and bailed out:

```
var $a = $('.lexicon a');
$a.each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('id'));
})
```

I also then need a line following this, that reads the last letter of the current URL (there will be 26 of course) and sets a class to the appropriate a-Tag so that I can style it. (jquery or php??)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `$(this).attr('href', 'mylexicon/mypage-' + $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1]);`

Comment: Thanks - but that doesn't seem to effect anything:
    var $a = $('.lexicon a');
    $a.each(function(){
        $(this).attr('href', 'mylexicon/mypage-' + $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1]);
    })
Still remains
<div class="lexicon">
 <a id="letter-a"></a>
 <a id="letter-b"></a>
 <a id="letter-c"></a>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

There is some other ways but its a good practice to be familiar with this js functions too:
`indexOf()` and `substr()`

```
var _a = jQuery('.lexicon a');
    _a.each(function(){
       var _this = jQuery(this),// cache variable to boost speed
           total_id = jQuery(this).attr('id'),// grab id attribute
           altered = total_id.substr(total_id.indexOf('-')+1, total_id.length);// grab all content after '-'

      _this.attr('href', 'mylexicon/mypage-'+ altered);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks - tried this and simply get: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Thanks, I'd tried this and still have : ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu i dont think so. Problem is you didn't add jquery library or you didn't defined dollar sign as jquery alias. post edited.

Comment: Grrrrr - you're right of course - had the script there before I'd loaded my library - sorted and many thanks for the help :-)

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu you just lead him to wrong way with low knowledge about js/jQuery. Before any advice, educate more please.

Answer (score 0):

this should do what you need

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $a = $('.lexicon a');
       $a.each(function(){
           var string = $(this).attr('id');
           var lastCharacter = string.substr(string.indexOf('-')+1);

           $(this).attr('href', 'mylexicon/mypage-' + lastCharacter);  // add the link
           $(this).text( lastCharacter );   // add the last character as text 
           $(this).attr('class', 'classNae-' + lastCharacter);  // add unique class name for styling 
       });
});
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="lexicon">
    <a id="letter-a"></a>
    <a id="letter-b"></a>
    <a id="letter-c"></a>
</div>
```